# MQTT try retrying connection for WebSocket protocol even after if logout from my application

Tags: angular, websocket, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-sdk-js

Here is my code snippet

```
getClient(iotInput: IIotInput) {
        const accessKeyId = iotInput.accessKeyId;
        const secretKey = iotInput.secretAccessKey;
        const host = iotInput.endpoint;
        const clientId = Helper.generateUniqueKey(32);
        const region = iotInput.region;
        const sessionToken = iotInput.sessionToken;

        const config =
            iot.AwsIotMqttConnectionConfigBuilder.new_with_websockets()
                .with_client_id(clientId)
                .with_credentials(region, accessKeyId, secretKey, sessionToken)
                .with_keep_alive_seconds(30)
                .with_endpoint(host)
                .with_clean_session(true)
                .build();

        const mqttClient = new mqtt.MqttClient();
        return mqttClient.new_connection(config);
}

makeConnection(iotInput: IIotInput): any {
        const client = this.getClient(iotInput);
        let counter = 0;
        client.on('connect', () => {
            client.subscribe(iotInput.topic, 1);
            iotInput.connectionSuccessCallback();
        });

        client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
            const data = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(message);
            if (data) {
                counter++;
            }
            const receivedDataObject = JSON.parse(data);
            const responseCounter = receivedDataObject.responseCounter;

            if (iotInput.topic === topic) {
                iotInput.dataReceivedCallback(
                    JSON.parse(data),
                    responseCounter,
                    counter
                );
            }
        });
        client.on('interrupt', (error) => {
            Logger.warn(error);
        });
        client.on('disconnect', () => {
            iotInput.connectionFailureCallback();
        });

        const cleanUrl = Helper.cleanURL(window.location.pathname);
        if (cleanUrl in this.urlToClientMapping) {
            this.urlToClientMapping[cleanUrl].push(client);
        } else {
            this.urlToClientMapping[cleanUrl] = [];
            this.urlToClientMapping[cleanUrl].push(client);
        }
        return client;
    }

hitIotStreamApi() {
            let client = null;
            this.arguments.iotStreamData.iotInput.dataReceivedCallback = (
                response,
                totalValueCount,
                recivedDataCount
            ) => {
                if (totalValueCount)
                    this.topicDataMap.set(
                        this.arguments.iotStreamData.iotInput.topic,
                        totalValueCount
                    );

                let finalCount;
                if (recivedDataCount !== undefined) {
                    finalCount = recivedDataCount;
                }

                if (
                    this.topicDataMap.size > 0 &&
                    this.topicDataMap.get(
                        this.arguments.iotStreamData.iotInput.topic
                    ) &&
                    finalCount ===
                        this.topicDataMap.get(
                            this.arguments.iotStreamData.iotInput.topic
                        )
                ) {
                    this.arguments.partialBindFunction(response);
                    this.arguments.partialBindFunction({
                        status: 'CLOSED'
                    });
                    if (this.arguments.streamCloseCallback) {
                        this.arguments.streamCloseCallback();
                    }

                    // CLOSE CONNECTION
                    if (client !== null) {
                        client.unsubscribe(
                            this.arguments.iotStreamData.iotInput.topic
                        );
                        console.log('before disconnect');
                        client.disconnect();
                        console.log('after disconnect', client);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.arguments.partialBindFunction(response);
                }
            };

            this.arguments.iotStreamData.iotInput.connectionFailureCallback = (
                response
            ) => {
                if (this.arguments.streamCloseCallback) {
                    this.arguments.streamCloseCallback();
                }
                this.arguments?.errorFunction('IOT Connection not successful');
            };
            this.arguments.iotStreamData.iotInput.connectionLostCallback = (
                response
            ) => {
                if (this.arguments.streamCloseCallback) {
                    this.arguments.streamCloseCallback();
                }
                this.arguments.errorFunction('IOT Connection lost');
            };
            
                // client with help of above connection
            client = this.httpService.hitIotStream(
                this.arguments.iotStreamData.iotInput
            );
        }
```

this is error which i get over console

[image]

and this is network call after logout from application

[image]

I am frontend developer.

I developed a web application in Angular framework. In my application. I developed a feature in which I used the IOT service from AWS.

In which, I used a aws-iot-device-sdk-v2 in JavaScript. In that service I making a MQTT client and subscribe a topic which a published data from backend developer and I am data to plot on UI.

I unsubscribe that topic once I get full data. After completing my work if i logout from my application. After 5-10 mins MQTT connection call hit in the network tab with status of finished again and again multiple times. Also throwing error in browser console. I go through from MQTT.d.ts it suggest that connection is automatically closed once you to unsubscribe a topic.

Kindly help me in knowing why this MQTT connection calling in network of browser even after a logout from application and how can I stop it. Is it effect on the infrastructure of the application.